# downloading ios7.1 simulator in xcode

Tags: xcode, ios7, xcode5, ios6.1

I have downloaded and installed version 5.1.1 of xcode. I have problem with downloading the ios 7.0 simulator and ios6.1 simulator. It is staying without any progress. I am having MAcOSX 10.9.2 . Any work around for me?
[image]

Comment: It may take some time to download. You shouldn't have the iOS6 simulator unless you added it manually after updating.

Comment: Also, you mentioned `ios7.1 simulator` in the question title. You don't need to download it, – it should be already installed.